# Adding multiple empty rows to a csv file

Tags: python

I have a csv file with around 500 lines, i want to insert multiple empty rows for each row , i.e add 5 empty rows after each row, so i tried this

```
import csv
with open("new.csv", 'r') as infile:
    read=csv.reader(infile, delimiter=',')
    with open("output1.csv", 'wt') as output:
        outwriter=csv.writer(output, delimiter=',')
        i = 0
        for row in read:
             outwriter.writerow(row)
             i += 1
             outwriter.writerow([])
```

This creates 3 empty rows but not 5, i am not sure on how to add 5 rows for each row. what am i missing here

**Update:**
CSV File sample

```
No,First,Sec,Thir,Fourth
1,A,B,C,D
2,A,B,C,D
3,A,B,C,D
4,A,B,C,D
5,A,B,C,D
6,A,B,C,D
7,A,B,C,D
8,A,B,C,D
```

Adding the output csv file for answer code
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code fixes it from the answer given by John Anderson, adding an additional `newline=''` parameter inside the `open` method gives the exact number of empty rows in range

```
import csv
with open("new.csv", 'r') as infile:
    read=csv.reader(infile, delimiter=',')
    with open("output1.csv", 'wt',newline='') as output:
        outwriter=csv.writer(output, delimiter=',')
        for row in read:
             outwriter.writerow(row)
             for i in range(5):
                 outwriter.writerow([])
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code actually only adds one blank line. Use a loop to add as many as you want:

```
import csv
with open("new.csv", 'r') as infile:
    read=csv.reader(infile, delimiter=',')
    with open("output1.csv", 'wt') as output:
        outwriter=csv.writer(output, delimiter=',')
        for row in read:
             outwriter.writerow(row)
             for i in range(5):
                 outwriter.writerow([])
```

Comment: This actually adds 11 empty rows instead of  5

Comment: For my `csv` file, your original code adds one blank line after each line in the original file, and my code adds 5 blank lines for each line. Please show us a sample of you `csv` file. Perhap there is something odd in it.

Comment: Do your original `csv` lines happen to end with `\n\n`?

Comment: Added the csv file sample

Comment: When I copy your `csv` example to `new.csv` and run my code, I get 5 blank lines after each line in the `output1.csv` file. There must be something else happening. How are you running the code?

Comment: I am using pycharm

Comment: Added the output csv file image, please check

Comment: I don't think I can offer anything else. I am confident the problem is not the Python code that we are looking at. Something else is happening.

Comment: Probably you're running your code on the previous output file, effectively adding blank lines for each line, again and again. John's code works fine by me as well. The problem comes from you :)